# jquery percentage and min&max payment calculator

Tags: jquery, calculator, percentage, minmax

I had this one, which i founded a long time ago and edited for my needs. But right now, I am interested to edit it and add some functions.

For the moment it have fixed monthly fee, min&max loan and min&max loan time (months)

But I am very interested how to add function, if I will have two or more loans with different min&max loans, min&max months and monthly fee %.

```
    min: 5000,
    max: 100000,
    value: 15000,
    step: 1000,
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HVhyT/2/)

Just don't wan't to dublicate much staff and make it clean, would appreciate any help :)